# Export/print map in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm working with leaflet and pure JS/jQuery to make a choropleth map and i've a problem when i try to export it to a local file as PNG/PDF/etc. I want to save the map directly in the main folder, pressing a `control print button`, editing the default output path if it is possible.

In leaflet documentation appear [four plugins to make it](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport):

- using `Leaflet.print`: i couldn't apply it, maybe for my little knowledge in js/leaflet/mapfish to use it. There is no page demo available to see how works. Then i opened the html example on github, index.html, to see how works, but it is used Mapfish to make the print, using a `info.json` file... I have a layergroup using two jsons to paint and colour polygons, as you can see in the JSFiddle link below.
- using `Leaflet-image`: i applied it and it generated a map, only with the base of mapbox, at right side of the original map using a topright button.
- using `Leaflet-easyPrint`: it works: generate the control button at topleft (**OK, i like the button!**) and print the map BUT in the print preview it doesn't show the legend colours.
- using `leaflet.browser.Print`: similar as easyPrint in demo, but i do not want the whole browser view. I only want the map, so i didn't try it.

Also, i tried a [jQuery print plugin using map div id](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Print-Any-Part-Of-Your-Page-Print.html), but the export map had not the colour legend (and i want to save in a local file).

Therefore, is there a way to do it? If you can explain it to me step-by-step i would be very grateful.

This is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljetvd2x/6/) applying `leaflet-easyPrint` and `leaflet-image`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option here is to go with easyPrint. It does have the issue you are mentioning, see: https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint/issues but as far as i can tell they are supposed to be solved in the V2 branch: https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-easyPrint/tree/v2 Changes are undocumented so far, so to find out what's changed you need to go through the issues i posted before.

Comment: You are right: the plugin V2 works perfect to export the image (PNG) to a local file pressing a printing button (at topleft) in the map.

Now i want to do it but avoiding browser funcionality; simulating clicks (perhaps usign javascript) and save directly in path (that was my original aim haha). Thanks for the info!

Comment: Did you manage to trigger the image export by simulating clicks in the end? if so, would you share the code for that?

Comment: Warning! If you expect this to work across all browsers find another solutiion since dom-to-image does not work on IE